# Generalization of the min-entropy that looks at the top $n$ probabilities

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, approximation-theory, entropy

The min-entropy of a random variable $X$ can often be much easier to compute than the Shannon entropy. This is because the min-entropy is simply a function of the most probable value, and sometimes, due to the structure of the sample space of $X$, it can be much easier to locate the mode of $X$ than to perform a sum over (possibly infinitely many) terms.

We may ask if there are similar generalizations of the Shannon entropy which look only at the top $k$ values, leading to a sequence of entropies $H_k(X)$ such that $H_1(X)$ is the min-entropy, and $H_{|X|}(X)$ is the Shannon entropy. This would be a different sequence of generalized entropies than the Rényi entropy, which also includes the Shannon and min-entropies. The benefit is that since we only look at the top $N$ values, these would also be relatively easy to compute. **Are there any such generalized entropies that are well-known?**

Let's say that $p_n$ is the n'th largest entry in the probability vector. Then one simple idea I was playing with is the following:

$$
H_k(X) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k p_n \log p_n}{\sum_{i=1}^k p_n}
$$

In other words, the numerator is the "partial Shannon entropy" of only the $k$ most probable terms, normalized by the sum of those probabilities. This is equal to the min-entropy when $n = 1$, the Shannon entropy when $n = |X|$, and something else in between. It seems to have some pretty nice properties; we have $H_k(X) \leq H_{k+1}(X)$  and so on. It seems unlikely that I am the first person to look at this metric; **has it and its properties been studied and does it have a name?**

Originally asked at MSE here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550813/generalization-of-the-shannon-entropy-that-looks-at-the-n-most-probable-values

EDIT: just in case this rings any bells, the metric suggested above can be viewed as a kind of cross entropy. Let's say that $X$ is our original random variable, and $X_n$ is a new derived random variable which is the restriction of $X$ to the $n$ most probable outcomes (breaking ties between equally probable events in any arbitrary way we'd like, as it doesn't matter). Then the metric I suggested is the cross entropy $H(X_n \times X)$. It works very well and is such a simple idea that I was hoping there'd be some references on it, but perhaps not.

Comment: What is the min-entropy good for?

Comment: The min-entropy is a special case of the Rényi entropy, which is a family of entropies that generalize Shannon's original and shares many of the same properties. The Rényi entropy is used pretty frequently in different fields and some uses are here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#:~:text=The%20R%C3%A9nyi%20entropy%20is%20important,as%20a%20measure%20of%20entanglement.

Comment: The min entropy has seen some use in cryptography, apparently in randomness extraction, but for my purposes I sometimes use it because it is "good enough" and easy to compute, and has the nice properties that all Rényi entropies do (e.g. is maximized at the uniform distribution, is additive for independent events, etc)

Comment: Adding to that: if a distribution has min-entropy $t$, then we know that every draw gives $t$ fresh random bits. Whereas distributions of the form $(1-\epsilon, \epsilon/n, \dots, \epsilon/n)$ have arbitrarily high entropy but the vast majority of draws give almost no information.